# How to search the related rows when i the enter the username name D.O.B or email in the inputs?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

login.php

```
                <?php

                $error="";
                 include_once 'connect.php';
                 session_start();

                 if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                                header('location:welcome.php');
                        }

                 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                   // username and password sent from form 

                   $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
                   $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

                   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' ";
                   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
                   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                   $hashed_password=$row['password'];
                   if(password_verify($mypassword, $hashed_password)) {

                     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
                     $_SESSION['id']=$row['userid'];
                     header("location: welcome.php");
                     exit();
                }    
                  else 
                  {
                     $error = " Invalid Username or Password ";
                    }
                }


                ?>
                <html>

                   <head>
                      <title>Login Page</title>

                      <style type = "text/css">
                         body {
                            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            font-size:14px;
                         }
                         label {
                            font-weight:bold;
                            width:100px;
                            font-size:14px;
                         }
                         .box {
                            border:#666666 solid 1px;
                         }

                         .button {
                            background-color: #4CAF50;
                            border: none;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 10px 20px;
                            text-align: center;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            display: inline-block;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            margin: 4px 2px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                }
                      </style>

                   </head>

                    <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">
                        <div align = "center">
                            <div style = "margin:30px">
                                <form action = "" method = "post">
                                  <label>Username : </label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                                  <label>Password : </label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                                  <input class="button" type = "submit" value = " login "/><br /> 
                                  <a href="index.php" class="button">Haven't Registered ? </a>
                                </form>
                                <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

welcome.php

```
                                 <?php
                                session_start();
                                if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                                    header('location:login.php');
                                }
                            ?>
                            <!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <body>
                            <?php
                            include_once 'connect.php';
                             $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                            echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
                            ?>
                                <br>
                            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                            <br>
                            <?php
                             //include_once 'connect.php';
                            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users");
                            echo "<table border='1'>
                            <tr>
                               <th>User_ID</th>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Username</th>
                               <th>E-mail</th>
                               <th>Department</th>
                               <th>Date_of_birth</th>
                               <th>Age</th>
                               <th>Image</th>
                               <th>Action</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>";
                             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                              echo "<tr>";
                             echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
                               echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                               echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                              echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                              echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
                             echo "<td>" . $row['Date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                             echo "<td><img alt='image' style='width:100px;height:50px;' src='upload/".$row['filename']."'></td>";
                             echo "<td> <a href='editform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                             echo "<td> <a href='deleteform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                              echo "</tr>";
                               }
                              echo "</table>";
                            ?>
                              <?php

                               //include_once 'connect.php';   
                                if(isset($_POST["happy"])){
                               if(empty($_POST["happy"])){ //not empty name
                                  echo '<br>';
                                      echo "No letter entered";
                                }else {
                                      $name = $_POST["happy"];
                                      $id = $_GET['id'];
                                      $sql="select name, username, email, Date_of_birth from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
                                      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                                      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                     // $sql="select name, username, email, Date_of_birth from `users`;";
                                   if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) === TRUE) {
                                                    print_r($id);
                              }else {
                             echo 'No record found';
                               }

                             }

                             }

                             ?>

                                    <form method="post">
                                        <br>
                                        Search: <input type="text" name="happy"><br><br>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </form>                 
                                </body>
                            </html>
```

editform.php

```
                        <?php
                         session_start();

                         if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                             header('location:login.php');

                         }

                         ?>

                        <?php
                        $nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $DateOfBirthErr = $departmentErr = $ageErr = $fileToUploadErr = $fileToUploadErrr = $fileToUploadErrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "";
                        $name = $email = $username = $DateOfBirth = $department = $age  = $filename  = "";

                        include_once 'connect.php';
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from `users` where userid ='$id'");
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                        //set a default variable to hold the original value if $_POST is not triggered
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $email = $row['email'];
                        $DateOfBirth = $row['Date_of_birth'];
                        $department = $row['department'];
                        $age = $row['age'];

                            // checking weather the form has been submitted before performing the update query
                        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

                            //Name Section    
                            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                                $nameErr = "Name is required";
                            } else {
                                $name = $_POST["name"];
                              // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
                                    $nameErr = "Only letters allowed no blank space";
                                }
                            }

                            //E-mail Section
                            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                                $emailErr = "Email is required";
                            } else {
                                $email = $_POST["email"];
                            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                    $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                                }
                            }

                            //Username Section
                            if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                                $usernameErr = "Username is required";
                            } else {
                                $username = $_POST["username"];
                             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username)) {
                                    $usernameErr = "Only letters allowed no blank space";
                                }
                            }

                            //D.O.B Section
                            if (empty($_POST["Date_of_birth"])) {
                                $DateOfBirthErr = "Date Of Birth is required";
                            } else {
                                $DateOfBirth = $_POST["Date_of_birth"];
                            }

                            //Department Section
                            if (empty($_POST["department"])) {
                                $departmentErr = "Department is required";
                            } else {
                                $department = $_POST["department"];
                            }

                            //Age Section
                          if (empty($_POST["age"])) {
                                $ageErr = "Age is required";
                            } 
                            elseif($_POST["age"]< 17 ) {
                                $ageErr = "Age should be above 18 years";
                            }
                            else {
                                $age = $_POST["age"];
                            }


                            //UPLOAD FILE
                            $uploaddir = 'upload/';
                            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
                            $imageFileType = pathinfo($uploadfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                            if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {  
                                // Check the image is actaully image or not
                                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]);
                                if ($check == false) {
                                    $fileToUploadErrrrr = "File is not an image.";

                                } 

                                // Check if file already exists
                                if (file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                                    $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "Sorry, file already exists.";
                                }

                                if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png") {
                                    $fileToUploadErr = "Sorry, only JPG,PNG files are allowed.";
                                } elseif ($_FILES['filename']['size'] > 500000) {

                                    $fileToUploadErrrr = "Sorry, your file is too large.";

                                } else {

                                  /*  if ($filename != '') {
                                        $target = "upload/" . $filename;
                                        unlink($target);
                                    }*/

                                    $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                                    if ($uploaded) {
                                        $file = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                                    } else {
                                        $file = $filename;
                                    }
                                }
                            }  else {
                                $file = $filename;
                            }


                            if ($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" && $DateOfBirthErr == "" && $departmentErr == "" && $ageErr == "" && $fileToUploadErr == "" && $fileToUploadErrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrrr == "") {
                                $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and userid !='$id'";
                                $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check);
                                $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
                                if ($da > 0) {
                                    echo "Username Already in Exists";
                                } else {
                                    if($file=="")
                                    {
                                $sql = "update `users` set name='$name', username='$username', email='$email', Date_of_birth='$DateOfBirth', department='$department', age='$age' where userid ='$id'";
                                if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                                        echo "Record updated successfully";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error(mysqli_query);
                                    }
                                    mysqli_close($mysqli);
                                    }
                                    else{

                                    $sql = "update `users` set name='$name', username='$username', email='$email', Date_of_birth='$DateOfBirth', department='$department', age='$age' , filename='$file' where userid ='$id'";
                                    $target = "upload/".$row['filename'];
                                    unlink($target);
                                    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                                        echo "Record updated successfully";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error(mysqli_query);
                                    }
                                    mysqli_close($mysqli);
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ?>


                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                        <head>
                            <style>
                                            .error {
                                                color:red;
                                            }

                                            .button {
                                                background-color: #4CAF50;
                                                border: none;
                                                color: white;
                                                padding: 10px 25px;
                                                text-align: center;
                                                text-decoration: none;
                                                display: inline-block;
                                                font-size: 16px;
                                                margin: 4px 2px;
                                                cursor: pointer;
                                            }
                                            .div1 {
                                                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                                                margin-top: -19px;
                                                margin-bottom: -25px;
                                                margin-left: -19px; 
                                            }

                                            .copy {
                                                border-radius: 4px;
                                                padding: 6px 20px;
                                               border-style: ridge;
                                            }

                                            .copy1{
                                                 border-radius: 4px;
                                                 padding: 6px 28px;
                                                 border-style: ridge;
                                            }

                                            .copy2{
                                                 border-radius: 4px;
                                                 padding: 4px 2px;

                                            }
                            </style>
                        </head>
            <body>

                    <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">
                    <h2 style="color:#009999">EDIT :</h2>

                        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?= $id ?>"/>
                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Name:</label><input class= "copy" style="margin-left: 52px" type="text" value="<?= $name ?>" name="name">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Username:</label><input type="text" class= "copy" style="margin-left:26px" value="<?= $username ?>" name="username">
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">E-mail:</label><input type="text" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value="<?= $email ?>" name="email">
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Date_of_birth: </label><input type="date" class= "copy1" value="<?= $DateOfBirth ?>" name="Date_of_birth">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $DateOfBirthErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Department:</label>
                                <select name="department"  class= "copy2" style="margin-left:14px" value="<?= $department ?>">
                                    <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                                    <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                                    <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                                    <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                                    <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                                    <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
                                </select>
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $departmentErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Age:</label><input type="number" class= "copy" style="margin-left:62px" value="<?= $age ?>" name="age">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $ageErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <label style="color:#0099ff">Select image : </label><input type="file" style="width:180px;height:100px;padding:10px;"  name="filename" >
                            <!--img src='' height='50px' width='50px'-->
                            <br>
                            <?php echo "<img alt='image' style='width:180px;height:100px;' src='upload/" . $row['filename'] . "'>";?>
                            <span class="error"><br><?php echo $fileToUploadErr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrrr; ?></span>
                            <br>

                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update"> 
                            <a href="welcome.php">Back</a>
                        </form>

                    </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

i have added one file name editform.php in that the all values are getting fetched except the department field i'm looking at it but  but don know where im going wrong and another issue is if i update the image then the updated image should be displayed on the same  page instead when i go back to my

Comment: Why are you not taking help from third party like : **Datatable**

Comment: i did not got what u said sir.

Comment: Do you get any problem please share errors if any ?

Comment: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 61

Comment: these errors im getting sir please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Query in your welcome.php

Use like and or clause for matching the given input to the different columns

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
 $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
?>
    <br>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<br>
<?php
 //include_once 'connect.php';
if(empty($_POST["happy"]))  
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users");
else {
    $search=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST["happy"]);

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users where name like '%$search%' or username like '%$search%' or email like '%$search%' or dob like '%$search%'");
}
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
   <th>User_ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>E-mail</th>
   <th>Department</th>
   <th>Date_of_birth</th>
   <th>Age</th>
   <th>Image</th>
   <th>Action</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td><img alt='image' style='width:100px;height:50px;' src='upload/".$row['filename']."'></td>";
 echo "<td> <a href='editform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
 echo "<td> <a href='deleteform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
 ?>

        <form method="post">
            <br>
            Search: <input type="text" name="happy"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>                 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 41

Comment: ah, please check the column name in your database and then apply in the query I wrote

Comment: thank you sir u had given dob which should be Date_of_birth so i changed dob to  Date_of_birth and it worked really thank you sir for helping. thanks once again.

Comment: sir in the above code the if statement which u have used after logout in that if statement u haven't used opening and closing braces

Comment: For single line statements, no need braces (Its optional)

Comment: i have added one file name editform.php in that all values are getting fetched except the department field i'm looking at it  
but don know where im going wrong and another issue is if i update the image then the updated image should be displayed on the same 
page instead when i go back to my welcome.php page and then return to the editform then it will show the updated image. 
please sir help me

Comment: Please create as another question

Comment: sir its showing u can add question only once 90min please help me in this question sir please

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259941/error-you-can-only-post-once-every-90-minutes-but-i-havent-posted-in-days

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501170/how-to-fetch-the-datbase-value

Comment: sir i have added new question as u said please go to this link